# How to substract and divide numbers in loops discord.js

Tags: discord.js, operators, commando

Coding a discord bot using the commando framework of discord.js v12.5, made an 'add' and 'multiply' command that adds every single number inputted by a user.

Here is the code for the 'add' command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando')

module.exports = class AddCommand extends Commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'add',
            group: 'math',
            memberName: 'add',
            description: 'Adds numbers',
            argsType: 'multiple',
        })
    }

    async run(message, args) {
        let sum = 0

        for (const arg of args) {
            sum += parseInt(arg)
        }

        const addCommandoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`SUCCESS\n\n${args.join(' + ')} = ${sum}`)
        .setColor('#1be730')
        message.channel.send(addCommandoEmbed)
    }
}
```

I don't know how to use logical operators to make it substract every single number given, and how to divide every single number given, and give the remainder at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[MathJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs)** library.

```js
const mathjs = require("mathjs");

const addCommandoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`SUCCESS\n\n${args.join(' + ')} = ${mathjs.evaluate(args.join(" + "))}`)
    .setColor('#1be730');

message.channel.send(addCommandoEmbed)
```